# Многократное воспроизведение одного wav файла поверх него самого

Tags: delphi, аудио, bass.dll

Нажатием клавиши "1" проигрывается wav аудио-файл следующим образом:

```
mciSendString(PChar('Play "res/snd/1A.wav"'), nil, 0, 0);
```

При повторном нажатии клавиши проигрывание аудио-файла происходит после того, как заканчивается предыдущее.

Как воспроизвести один аудио-файл несколько раз с эффектом наложения без остановки предыдущего?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ходе изучения данного вопроса, выяснилось, что наиболее лучшим решением является использование библиотеки Bass.dll. Скачать её можно по ссылке http://www.un4seen.com/

Инструкция по установке, если у кого-то возникли с этим трудности:

1. Поместить файл bass.dll в папку с программой;
2. В `Uses` добавить `Bass`;
3. К глобальным переменным добавить `Channel: Cardinal;`
4. В `FormCreate` пишем `BASS_Init(-1, 44100, 0, application.Handle, nil);`

Воспроизведение:

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if key=#49 then begin
    Channel := BASS_StreamCreateFile(FALSE, PChar('res/snd/1A.wav'), 0, 0, 0);
    BASS_ChannelPlay(Channel, False);
  end;
end;
```